# How can I execute JavaScript on button click (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently experimenting with my first chrome extension.

I wrote this **ui_popup.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="hide.js"></script>
    <style>
      button {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: red;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="triggerConsole"></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this **console.js**:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('triggerConsole').addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('test');
    });
});
```

The extension itsself is loaded without errors or anything.

The problem is that the console.log('test') is not logged to then console when I click that button.

I can't figure out what the problem is. How can I properly execute that JS after clicking the button?

Comment: I suspect you're just looking at the wrong console, that is the one of the open tab. If you open dev tools for your popup instead, logs should be there.

Comment: omg you're my savior, thank you. I'm a complete newbie at chrome extensions and looked at the wrong console as you suspected. thank you so much!

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova you should post your comment as the answer.